# Unity-Like Display Scaling in Other DEs

Tags: unity, gnome, display, kde, scaling

Within the display settings of Unity 7, there is a slider bar titled "Scale for menu and title bars".  Unlike the scaling options that I have found in other DEs, the slider in Unity allows scaling to values <1, which I have found significantly improves the experience of using Unity on non-HiDPI displays.

[image]

Does anyone know of a way to achieve the same result in other DEs?  I have a couple of machines running Gnome 3 and one running Plasma, and have not yet been able to identify any way of doing this - they allow scaling to values >1 to better facilitate HiDPI displays, but do not allow scaling to values <1.

Thanks in advance for any input you may have!